# wpf automatic event generation stub

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, event-handling

Why visual studio generates event method with number postfix, Ex: instead generating Click event of a `button` as `button_Click`, it generates `button_Click_1` where there is no `click` event present.

Comment: `Button_Click` gets generated I dont see why you got `Button_Click1`

Comment: Can't reproduce. It generates `Button_Click` for me. I guess you already have `Button_Click` method.

Comment: no there is not and facing same problem with each and every event method generation

Answer (score 0):

Well am quite certain you have a stale button_Click somewhere.. find it and remove it

Comment: first thing there is no stale button and second vs add number with each and every king of event method

Comment: please replace "king" with "kind"

Comment: and button with button_Click :)